# How can I properly fetch data using MagicalRecord for Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I am trying to fetch data from my `User` class:

```
@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

// Attributes
   @NSManaged var cAge: Int16
   @NSManaged var rAge: Int16
   @NSManaged var cIncome: Int64
   @NSManaged var rIncome: Int64
   @NSManaged var state: String
   @NSManaged var returnRate: Float

}
```

Here is my fetch call:

```
let user = User.mr_findAll()! as! [User]
print(user)
```

Here is the output from `print(user)`:

```
[<User: 0x2812da300> (entity: User; id: 0x2831da740 <x-coredata:///User/t34A918DC-3B79-4ECC-91EF-16F658B20B8A2> ; 
data: {
    cAge = 23;
    cIncome = 125086;
    rAge = 50;
    rIncome = 365048;
    returnRate = "0.78";
    state = In;
})]
```

How can I just retrieve the data, and not all the other information?

Comment: coredata is not like the other database for eg mongoDB where u can query exact property from a table. but in coredata, u will be getting an NSManagedObject while querying. there you have to take the property u want. Magical record offers many apis to fetch the data veryhandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to loop through the results to extract the attributes from the User class.

```
let users = User.mr_findAll()! as! [User]
for user in users{
     print(user.cAge)
}
```